# How to get blocked threads counter trying enter lock section in C#

Tags: c#, multithreading

I need to know how many threads trying enter critical section. I have a collection of let's say devices, and i want to get the device which have smallest amount of pending threads.

```
List<Device> devices;
.
.
.

Device device = Device.getAvailableDevice( devices );

lock (device)
{
     device.DoSomeWork();
}
```

I know i can use some counter, but i'm trying to avoid it.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a fundamental flaw in your logic.

I assume you intend the method `Device.getAvailableDevice( devices )` to return a device that is actually available - or even the device that will be the first to become available. But you lock the device only after that call. That means that more than one thread may observe the device to be available, and subsequently try to lock it. As a result, threads are indeed waiting in queues to obtain the device, that was supposed to be 'available'. And as a consequence, you ask how you can find out how many are waiting, as you want that information to implement `Device.getAvailableDevice( devices )`, if not to find one that nobody is waiting for, then at least to find the one that will become available soon.

What you should do instead, is create some sort of device manager, that holds two collections: available devices and devices in use. The manager should have two methods: `GetAvailableDevice` which return a device that was available and sets it to in-use, and `ReturnDevice` which makes a device available again (i.e. move it from the in-use devices collection to the available devices collection).

Those two methods lock on the device manager, but not on individual devices. The `GetAvailableDevice` call is blocking, threads might be waiting for the manager to return one. The `ReturnDevice` call is not blocking, in the sense that it returns immediately.

For more information on how to implement such a structure, I suggest you read "Threading in C#" by Joseph Albahari, see http://www.albahari.com/threading/.

A solution based on a queue per device needs to decide now what device will be busy or available in the future. And when it decides, the first thing that happens is that the thread that requested it starts waiting for that specific device (possibly for a zero period of time).

A solution based on a single queue for all devices combined does not need to predict the future. As a device becomes available, any device, it gives it to a waiting thread that can immediately start to use it. Threads wait for the device manager to give them a device (possibly for a zero period of time), but not for the device that is given to them. This solution also avoids the situation where a thread is still waiting for a device, while another device has already become available, with no threads waiting for it.

Comment: Thanks for response Kris.
I think i confused you with the method name. Actually getAvailableDevice should return the device with smallest amount of pending threads, not the one which is not blocked yet. I'm trying to implement some logic that will spread homogeneously my requests over devices i have. So if i have three devices, and two of them have two threads pending each, and one have only one thread running, the getAvailableDevice will return the third device.

Comment: No, you did not confuse me. In fact, your reply confirms I am correct. You should not keep track of the waiters per device, only of the total waiters globally, fo all devices combined (but let the system do that for you). As a device becomes available, any device, give it to some waiting thread. Note that this will distribute the load evenly also in cases where some threads need a device for a short period of time, while others need it for a long time. Your solution would not be able to do that.

Comment: I see your point now. In this case it maybe will be even more correct to threat available devices as thread pool. All jobs coming trying to get device, if there available devices (threads) path the job to device (thread), if no wait until some device released.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know there is no other way than using a counter.
Increment it before the lock and decrease it after the lock block.

Comment: This is what i'm doing now, but what if thread interrupted or some other exception and so on. Did not want to manage it by my self, but it looks like there is no choice. Thanks.

Comment: I think so too ;), to handle exceptions etc decrease your counter in the finalize block for example...